# Swift 4 saying these two lines are deprecated... tried everything

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode9

How do I fix these two lines of code in Swift 4?

```
let first = String(characters.prefix(1)).capitalized
let other = String(characters.dropFirst())
```

Apparently using 'characters' is deprecated....

The official warning:

'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly

Comment: Assuming this is inside a String extension instance method or computed property `let first = String(prefix(1)).capitalized` and `let other = String(dropFirst())`

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks a lot